# How to not send sms or emails when running mocha test suite

Tags: twilio, mocha.js, sendgrid, mailgun

I'm running end-to-end tests with Mocha, but I do not want SMS or emails to be sent by the test suite. What is the best practice for skipping over these functions if testing, and running them when in production?

Comment: General comment here but most frameworks can permit you to use a different endpoint during development. I’m not specifically knowledgeable about mocha but you can probably find it in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

You need dependency injection to use mock APIs during testing.

A simplest approach for a smaller project is to set an environment variable when running the test (e.g., ENV=TEST), and change the application code to skip the api calling or call a mock API (which may be logging the calls) when the environment variable value matches the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **mock** the implementation of the SMS/E-mail from the library that you're using. Mocha suggest [in their documentation](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki#mocks-stubs--spies) to use Simon.JS, Simple-Mock, and Nock.